# in a listview i have an object with data that will fill a position

Tags: java, android, listview

In a `ListView` I have an object with data that will fill a position in the list I'm trying to get all data from the position and put them in the next `Activity`.

```
btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

         newTitle = edtTitle.getText().toString();
         newYear = edtYear.getText().toString();
         newAuthor = edtAuthor.getText().toString();
         newSummary = edtSummary.getText().toString();

         Book newBook = new Book(newTitle,Integer.parseInt(newYear),newAuthor,newSummary);

         books.add(newBook);

         bookAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

         Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Data added",LENGTH_SHORT);
         toast.show();

         edtTitle.setText("");
         edtYear.setText("");
         edtAuthor.setText("");
         edtSummary.setText("");
    }
});
```

Comment: put your adapter code

Answer (score 1):

Make `Book` class `implements Serializable` and use `OnItemClickListener` in your `listView` activity

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3)
        {
            Book clickedBook = books.get(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, NextActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("SELECTED_BOOK", clickedBook);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

And in `NextActivity`

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        Book selectedBook = (Book)extras.get("SELECTED_BOOK");
    }
```